# eclipse pde - Access cdt managebuilder definitions of a project

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-plugin

For eclipse pde, How do I access cdt build definitions of a project from code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look, for instance, at `org.eclipse.cdt.ui.actions.ChangeBuildConfigActionBase` - it iterates through build configs when showing the menu.